# robot_localization tf tree structure

Tags: ros, imu, navigation, ptam, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having trouble getting robot_localization to work.

I have read through the robot_localization wiki, the tf wiki and the REP-105/103 doc but I still don't understand how to structure the tree for robot_localization.

I have 2 frames_ids from IMU and PTAM messages.

Concepts i don't understand:

1. Where do these map, odom, base_link frames come from? Do I generate those using tf as a virtual representation of the real world sensors and their relative positions and orientations?
2. If so how do I link the supplied frames to the tree I create? In the doc it says map -> odom -> base_link. Do I also link base_link -> imu and odom -> ptam?
3. Finally do I supply robot_localization with the odom and base_link or imu and ptam frames?

The only way I have ever managed to get robot_localization to produce messages in the /odometry/filtered topic is to use the sensor frames directly but this doesn't seem the correct way to do it.

Any example code or step by step instructions would be great. Docs have not helped me with my confusion. I just don't understand how to piece it all together.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216826/robot_localization-tf-tree-structure/) by [K7](https://answers.ros.org/users/23630/k7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 94 on 2015-08-31

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [paul3333](https://answers.ros.org/users/68392/paul3333/) on 2021-03-04**:
@K7  where you able to solve this problem? Im facing the exact same issue as you did but can not fix it.

Would be great if you could share your solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think this is really more of a `tf` question. Let's ignore sensors and such for a second and just focus on two coordinate frames, *odom* and *base_link*. When your robot starts out, it is at position (0, 0) in the *odom* frame. It then drives, say, four meters forward, turns left, and drives six meters. Its position in the *odom* frame is now (4, 6). This information can be expressed in two ways:

1. A ROS message (in this case, nav_msgs/Odometry) that contains the robot's world pose (and velocity, but let's ignore that for now). We fill out this message with the robot's current pose and send it off to be consumed.
2. A transform from the *odom* frame to the *base_link* frame. This contains the exact same information, but is sent via `tf` instead.

`robot_localization` produces both (1) and (2).

Now let's say we have an IMU on your robot, but instead of facing forward, we turn it sideways. Additionally, we mount it 0.3 meters to the left of the robot's centroid. We can represent this offset as a transform, and use the `static_transform_publisher` package to continuously send out a transform from *base_link* to your IMU's `frame_id` (e.g., *imu*). Now, before we can use that IMU data, we need to make sure to transform it into the correct coordinate frame. In this case, `robot_localization` uses the `tf` libraries to look up what the transform is between *base_link* and *imu*, and then "corrects" (transforms) the IMU data into the robot's body (base_link) frame, and then passes it on to the filter to be fused.

Now let's say you have a LIDAR on your robot, and you define a *base_link*->*lidar* transform using `static_transform_publisher`. Your LIDAR detects an obstacle 10 meters away at 30 degrees. You have a node somewhere that needs to know where that obstacle is in the *odom* frame and not the *lidar* frame, so it uses the `tf` libraries to look up a transform from *lidar* to *odom*, which produces the location of that obstacle in the *odom* frame.

Note that you can name the frames whatever you want. REP-105 just gives suggestions that are commonly used. For PTAM, you can see if PTAM lets your specify the `frame_id`. If it does, you can set it to odom. If not, you can either (a) just set the `odom_frame` and `world_frame` parameters to *ptam*, or you can specify a static transform of 0 between *ptam* and *odom*.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2015-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [K7](https://answers.ros.org/users/23630/k7/) on 2015-08-31**:
Yes! Thanks Tom, that has helped a lot. Now to try and put the theory to use...

**Comment by [K7](https://answers.ros.org/users/23630/k7/) on 2015-08-31**:
Great I think it's working now. Now I'm just getting some major drift, but that's another story ;)
Can't thank you enough for your help, you have saved me hours of frustration.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2015-09-01**:
No problem! Good luck.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2021-03-06**:
Please don't use an *answer* to leave a *comment*. This isn't a forum

**Comment by [peter_feng](https://answers.ros.org/users/140466/peter_feng/) on 2023-02-24**:
Hi Tom.IMU sensor or Lidar sensor are easier to understand.Because they are only relative to the robot body `base_link`.So we can publish the transform between them using `/tf`.

What about GPS?The GPS sensor also has the transform to robot body.How should I publish the transform relationship between them?
If I set GPS  sensor's `fram_id` to `gps`, and publish the `tf` from `base_link` to `gps`.Does the `robot_localization` package think that the gps data `/fix` is not based on the map framwork?
If I set GPS  sensor's `fram_id` to `map`, and publish the `tf` from `base_link` to `map`.Will this cause conflict?

How should I configure it?

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2023-02-24**:
@peter_feng  you should create a new question instead of making a comment on a nearly 8 year old answer. This will give you more visibility